# How to run exe or bat file with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, batch-file

I hope someone can help. I'm trying to run a file by a button click but both methods don't work with IE or Firefox.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>

<body>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

function myFunction1(){
batch = "C:\\personallaner\\istbat.bat"; 
obj=new ActiveXObject('WScript.Shell');
   obj.Run (batch); 
}

function myFunction2(){
var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var commandtoRun = "C:\\personallaner\\istbat.bat"; 
oShell.ShellExecute(commandtoRun,"","","open","1");
};

</script>

<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" onclick="myFunction1()" value="a"/>
<input id="button" type="submit" name="button" onclick="myFunction2();" value="b"/>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Explain how they don't work. Is there an error? Does nothing happen? Something else?

Comment: Suppose it is possible to execute some program from `javascript`, someone will execute `C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c shutdown -r` or some other command which will be a huge security fault. No, it is not possible until someone enable `ActiveXObject` which is disabled by default.

Comment: Try to execute it with a HTA file not html !

Comment: Im sorry that i didnt explain. I want a simple website with 2 buttons and both buttons should run a bat file. If i try to run the javascript method it just happen nothing.

Comment: I think the link from Anon Coward should help. I try it later.